# How to populate Grid View with images from PHP MySql in Android?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

I want to retrieve all the images and populate GridView from PHP MySql Database. I'm using JSON parsing.But in my grid view is nothing display images from PHP and also nothing any error.So then why not show the images in Gridview in my application.What is wrong with the code. Thanks to appreciate.

Here is my Adapter code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mThumbIds;

    public GridViewAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data )
    {
        this.context= context;
        mThumbIds= data;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position ;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position).get("image"));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;

    }
}
```

Here is Activity code.

```
package com.photo_app;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class Photo_Gallery extends Activity
{
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    GridView gridview;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String URL_PHOTO_GALLERY = "http://192.168.1.102/timesofindia/admin/photo_gallery.php";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }


    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Photo_Gallery.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Wait");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {

            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL_PHOTO_GALLERY);
            System.out.println("Json String = " + jsonobject.toString());


            try
            {
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("photo_gallary");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    arraylist.add(map);
                    Log.e("arraylist","=");
                }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photoGallery);
            adapter = new GridViewAdapter();
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anju, where is your images are? in mThumbIds array or in arraylist array???

Comment: have you designed custom row layout for grid item?

Comment: @BellaSwan I think issue is in fetching images and its array, she has taken dynamic imageview, so its not the issue.

Comment: @Pratik : - Images in  Arraylist from json in Activity not in mThumbIds in Adapter.Ho to do this.

Comment: @anjupatel Its very easy dear. If you dont mind then can you please send me your code. let me get back to you with working code.

Comment: You just need to pass the array to adapter...

Comment: @pratik please don't talk to other people in that way. It's disgusting.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry dear? What wrong I have did? I am only talking about issue.

Comment: @Pratik: Yah, but How to send you? I have post all the code in the above.

Comment: @pratik :- i have sent to u.

Comment: @anjupatel is your url is a local url from where you getting your images??

Comment: images are getting from PHP MySql db.

Comment: @anjupatel but db is located locally na? I mean in your PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
package com.photo_app;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class Photo_Gallery extends Activity
{
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    GridView gridview;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private String URL_PHOTO_GALLERY = "http://192.168.1.102/timesofindia/admin/photo_gallery.php";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_gallery);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }


    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Photo_Gallery.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Wait");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {

            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL_PHOTO_GALLERY);
            System.out.println("Json String = " + jsonobject.toString());


            try
            {
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("photo_gallary");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++)
                {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("image"));
                    arraylist.add(map);

                    Log.e("arraylist","=" + arraylist.add(map) );
                }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photoGallery);
            adapter = new GridViewAdapter(Photo_Gallery.this,arraylist);
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }



}
```

//Adapter Code:

```
package com.photo_app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.androidquery.AQuery;

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> mThumbIds=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    AQuery aQuery;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public GridViewAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data )
    {
        this.context= context;
        mThumbIds= data;
        aQuery=new AQuery(context);
    }



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mThumbIds.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_gallery_list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        aQuery.id(holder.imageView).image(mThumbIds.get(position).get("flag"),true,true);

        return convertView;

    }

    class ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

//photo_gallery_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: **Now you have also taken the custom ow layout,,the problem doesn't exist there** You are making the code complex by introducing new things to a newbie

Comment: @BellaSwan not at all, I am giving her a chance to learn nice thing, so she can b take care in future and go with proper way. And this is not complex at all. Why you taking me wrong way, can you just tell me?

Comment: @BelaaWsan:- I have done my half part of retrieve the images from php server but the issue is , i don't understand how to display in GridView.Thats it.

Comment: @Pratik:- I have run your code but getting null pointer exception. I'm not waisting your time ok. You have did perfect code then why getting nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the data to the adapter. So, create a `constructor` which accepts the data and use it as you want in `getView`..

> Pass the required data from the Activity to Adapter(it can be of any type. I have just given example to pass `Integer[]`)

```
public GridViewAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> data )
    {
        this.context= context;
        mThumbIds= data;
    }
```

and pass it in you activity as :

```
GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this,your_data_array);
```

Update :

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
         imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get(position).get("key")); // assuming key contains the resource id
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;

    }
```

Comment: She is trying to load the image from url, she need to pass url arraylist to the adapter. Integer is not going to serve the purpose.

Comment: whatever is the `DataType`..it's just an example..she need to change it as her requirement. I showed it because I found `public Integer[] mThumbIds = {};` in her code..

Comment: @Bella Swan :- I have edited with your code but the issues occured in Adapter class. The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>.  imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

Comment: @BellaSwan your answer is fine, but I think anju is newbie, so will not understood.

Comment: yes..and **this is not spoon-feeding site** .you need her to learn also how to `code` ..so better to show her step by step than directly code for her

Comment: @BellaSwan I am doing same dear, I will send her commented code so she can understand how to do stuffs with it.

Comment: @BellaSwan:- Can you please see my Edited Post above . I have post my change code gain.

Comment: @anjupatel sent you email, just import that code and run it, it will work.

Comment: @BellaSwan :- String is not applicable for the setImageResource.

Comment: @anjupatel you have to use image downloader library, which I have used in your code, you will know, how it will work.

Comment: You need to take Integer in `HashMap`as `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>`

Comment: @BellaSwan I think taking Integer is wrong way, because we have image url so use it directly.

Comment: hey I don't know her code..You have her code so you can say like that. I can just see the code she shared here...and @anjupatel I guess this is not your actual question. Your motto is fulfilled other part is left to you to change the code accordingly..You might have taken the data structure in wrong way.I can't suggest you to change the data structure,You need to be careful while taking any data structure. and as pratik said, if it contains the url,take the data structure accordingly..